# Laravel Authentication doesnt work after converting my project to desktop app using php desktop chrome

Tags: php, laravel, phpdesktop

So I have a working Laravel project uploaded on an online domain name. I need to convert this into an offline desktop application. I have made the research and found php desktop chrome:
the project converted successfully but on a successful login, it redirects me to /home then back again to /login

I have noticed that my online application has 2 cookies while on phpdesktop app there are no cookies being registered.

I used SQLite for DB and the connection is working fine (tested to insert to DB).

I am new to Laravel. sorry for my poor english plz help

Comment: Sessions are tracked via the session cookie so if that isnt being set, that would definitely  make logins not work as you describe.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop/issues/232